# Set Retrofit response into NavigationDrawer header

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, retrofit2

This is the standard code generated by the Android Studio, with my method initAccount(), where I get the user model and write it in myAccount variable. When I do a Snackbar or something, the data is present, but when I want to write the user data into the navigation header, an error appears:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.vegevgsdsfa/com.sgsgsgdbsdg.activities.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String com.nfjg;lahjg;glsg.models.User.getNickName()' on a
>   null object reference

It's line `nick.setText(myAccount.getNickName());`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

ApiCaller userInfo;
User myAccount;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initAccount();

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    View headerView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main);
    TextView nick = (TextView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.txt_nickname);
    nick.setText(myAccount.getNickName());

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

private void initAccount() {
    userInfo = Core.buildInterceptCaller();
    Call<User> call = userInfo.showAccount();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                myAccount = response.body();
            } else
                Snackbar.make(getCurrentFocus(), response.code(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}

}
```

I'm new to this and I can not understand what the problem is. Thank you for attention.

Answer (score 1):

You should set nickname after response has arrived after the onResponse of retrofit is called. But now you are setting nick name in onCreate means retrofit hasnot completed its work but you are trying to set nickname.So its returning null in setnickname.

```
private void initAccount() {
    userInfo = Core.buildInterceptCaller();
    Call<User> call = userInfo.showAccount();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                myAccount = response.body();
                nickname.setText(myAccount.getNickName); //Nickname global
            } else
                Snackbar.make(getCurrentFocus(), response.code(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This means that the initialization of the view must be carried out in the initAccount()?

Comment: yes ofcourse. i do have updated my answer. make nickname text view global. You can try butterknife for getting id of view. i would be much simple. No need of findViewByID. This is extra suggestion. :D